# Add PowerShell package as native dependency

Tags: powershell, browser, dependency-injection, blazor-webassembly, replit

How should one add the PowerShell package as a [Native dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-native-dependencies?view=aspnetcore-6.0)? In spite of adding it one is unable to run basic PowerShell commands to show output on the screen. PFB REPL link.

https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/GQacljYn3647KP3G59

The HTML and C# `Hello World` are working. However, the PowerShell `Hello World` doesn’t work.

[image: PowerShell 'Hello World' not working]

Expecting the [REPL link](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com) and or a screenshot of PowerShell `Hello World` on the browser, in the answer.

Comment: Probably there is no way, as Powershell is *less native* than C# for .NET applications. Thus you might be better to add Powershell package as a software-based dependency, then call powershell executable supplying it scripts via command line or parameters.

Comment: @Vesper, It's probably [just a specific DLL failing to load](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13755). See [demo for PS7 running on a browser](https://fmichaleczek.github.io/PowerShellLab/). Could you share a REPL link for running `Write-Output`?